# Using Elixir to talk to Rust via Ports, what am I getting wrong?

Tags: rust, port, elixir, native

I'm in the process of writing a tutorial, because I couldn't find a simple example anywhere, of communicating between Elixir and Rust via a Port.

I can get Rustler to work, but that is a NIF, not a Port.

I'm missing something fundamental in my code. I'm not sure if I'm missing something basic in stdio or if it's something else, but I've tried a lot of different things.

I *can* get port communication to work with a very basic program in Rust:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    println!("hello world!");
}
```

I can get this to get pulled into my iex -S mix by running this port:

```
defmodule PortExample do

  def test() do
    port = Port.open({:spawn_executable, "_build/dev/rustler_crates/portexample/debug/portexample"}, [:binary])
    Port.info(port)
    port
end
```

Here's what the iex for that looks like:

```
Interactive Elixir (1.4.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> PortExample.test()
#Port<0.9420>
iex(2)> flush()
{#Port<0.9420>, {:data, "hello world!\n"}}
:ok
iex(3)>
```

I can do the same using a porcelain library call:

```
  alias Porcelain.Result
  def porcelain() do
    result = Porcelain.exec("_build/dev/rustler_crates/portexample/debug/portexample",["hello", "world"])
    IO.inspect result.out
  end
```

corresponding iex:

```
iex(3)> PortExample.porcelain()
"hello world!\n"
"hello world!\n"
iex(4)>
```

However, as soon as I start using a Rust library with some form of input/output, things start falling over.

For example, Rust code:

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write, Read};

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    let mut output = String::new();
    for i in 0..2 {
        match io::stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
            Ok(n) => {
                println!("input: {}", input.trim());
                io::stdout().flush();
            }
            Err(error) => println!("error: {}", error),
        }
    }
}
```

I can get it to compile and run in the command line:

```
hello
input: hello
world
input: hello
world
```

However, when I call it from an Elixir port:

```
iex(12)> port = PortExample.test()
#Port<0.8779>
iex(13)> Port.command(port, "hello")
true
iex(14)> Port.command(port, "world")
true
iex(15)> Port.command(port, "!")    
true
iex(16)> Port.command(port, "more")
true
iex(17)> flush()
:ok
iex(18)> Port.info(port)
[name: '_build/dev/rustler_crates/portexample/debug/portexample',
 links: [#PID<0.271.0>], id: 4697, connected: #PID<0.271.0>, input: 0,
 output: 15, os_pid: 21523]
```

I get no data from it at all! However, the `Port.info(port)` call shows that its received 15 bytes. It just hasn't posted returned anything at all to the port. I've been trying to read other code and I thought I was doing things similar enough that it should work, but it doesn't.

I thought: maybe the buffer isn't flushed? so I flush the buffer in Rust.
I thought: maybe the loop is hanging, so I limited it to only a few passes.
When I try to run this same code through the porcelain call, it hangs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're reading a line of input in the Rust code, which will read until a `\r\n` or `\n`, but you're not sending the newline character from Elixir. If you change all the `Port.command` calls to add a `\n` after the message, it works:

```
iex(1)> port = Port.open({:spawn_executable, "a"}, [:binary])
#Port<0.1229>
iex(2)> Port.command(port, "hello")
true
iex(3)> flush()
:ok
iex(4)> Port.command(port, "hello\n")
true
iex(5)> flush()
{#Port<0.1229>, {:data, "input: hellohello\n"}}
:ok
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it. I knew it had to be a fundamental thing I was missing.